R Cran - Nested irregular xml with xml's attributes as dataframe's col names
I have a big xml file produced by windows log and i need to import it into R to analyse some correlation beetween the events logged.
The problem i encounter is that the events'details (EventData) are kept as xml's attributes and the number of attributes changes by the kind of the events.
The simplified xml to import is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Events>
    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
        <System>
            <EventID>259</EventID>
            <Version>0</Version>
            <Level>2</Level>
            <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-07-10T15:02:35.203376200Z"/>
        </System>
        <EventData>
            <Data Name="TCP">0</Data>
            <Data Name="InterfaceIP">0.0.0.0</Data>
            <Data Name="Source">192.168.109.4</Data>
            <Data Name="QNAME"/>
        </EventData>
    </Event>
    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
        <System>
            <EventID>256</EventID>
            <Version>0</Version>
            <Level>4</Level>
            <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-07-10T15:02:35.203362300Z"/>
        </System>
        <EventData>
            <Data Name="TCP">0</Data>
            <Data Name="InterfaceIP">0.0.0.0</Data>
            <Data Name="Source">192.168.109.4</Data>
            <Data Name="QNAME">microsoft.com.</Data>
            <Data Name="QTYPE">0</Data>
            <Data Name="XID">22342</Data>
            <Data Name="Port">65220</Data>
            <Data Name="Flags">16979</Data>
            <Data Name="BufferSize">108</Data>
         </EventData>
    </Event>
</Events>


This is what I expect.
The code I wrote is:
library(xml2)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)


file_dns <- c("./test_ridotto_2.xml")
read_xml(file_dns) -> dns


dns_items <- tibble(
   event_id =  xml_find_all(x = dns, xpath = "/Events/Event/System/EventID") |> xml_text(),
   time_created = xml_find_all(x = dns, xpath = "/Events/Event/System/TimeCreated") |> xml_attr(attr = "SystemTime"),
   info4 = xml_find_all(x = dns, xpath = "/Events/Event/EventData") |> as_list()
)

The problem I have, is that I don't understand how to continue to split columns and give them the name of the attribute, as the number of attributes and so the number of columns change row by row and depend from the type of the event logged.
I tried the unnest_wider command but it lost attributes and seems slow on my simplified test file.
Production file is 1Gb.
How to obtain the expected result?

Do you have a fixed set of event attributes you wish to extract or should final result include columns for all existing attributes?

This is expressed in a very confusing way. I think perhaps you are referring to elements such as <Data Name="QTYPE">0</Data> as "attributes". While they may represent attributes of some object in your data model, at the XML level they are elements, not attributes.

An approach using xml2::as_list. The attributes of the elements stay intact even when they are put in a dataframe/tibble with as_tibble.
The performance will be limited by purrr since it has to process columns element-wise.
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

as_tibble(as_list(read_xml("event.xml"))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(Events) %>% 
  mutate(EventID = purrr::map_vec(System, ~ unlist(.x$EventID)), 
         TimeCreated = purrr::map_vec(System, ~ attr(.x$TimeCreated, "SystemTime"))) %>%
  select(-System) %>% 
  unnest(EventData) %>% 
  mutate(name = purrr::map_vec(EventData, ~ unlist(attributes(.x))), 
         value = purrr::map_vec(EventData, ~ toString(.x)), EventData = NULL) %>% 
  pivot_wider()

output
# A tibble: 2 × 11
  EventID TimeCreated     TCP   InterfaceIP Source QNAME QTYPE XID   Port  Flags
  <chr>   <chr>           <chr> <chr>       <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 259     2024-07-10T15:… 0     0.0.0.0     192.1… ""    NA    NA    NA    NA
2 256     2024-07-10T15:… 0     0.0.0.0     192.1… "mic… 0     22342 65220 16979
# ℹ 1 more variable: BufferSize <chr>


This script extracts out the eventID and createdtime from each event and then loops through the events and extracts out the data elements and node ID to create a dataframe for your final answer.
See the comments below for a step-by-step.
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

#read page and strip namespace
page <- read_xml(text)
xml_ns(page)

#find the events nodes
events <- xml_find_all(page, ".//Event")

#get the eventID and Created time
eventID <- xml_find_first(events, ".//EventID") %>% xml_text()
CreatedTime <-xml_find_first(events, ".//TimeCreated") %>% xml_attr("SystemTime")

#loop through the events and extract the data
#make a data frame and create the proper column headings
dfs <- lapply(events, function(node){
   data <- xml_find_all(node, ".//Data") %>% xml_text()
   tag <- xml_find_all(node, ".//Data") %>% xml_attrs() %>% unlist()
   names(tag)<-NULL
   df<-as.data.frame(t(data))
   names(df) <- tag
   df
})

#make a data frame for the answer
answer <- bind_rows(dfs)

#add the event ID and timecreated
answer <-bind_cols(EventID=eventID, CreatedTime=CreatedTime, answer)

  EventID                    CreatedTime TCP InterfaceIP        Source          QNAME QTYPE   XID  Port Flags BufferSize
1     259 2024-07-10T15:02:35.203376200Z   0     0.0.0.0 192.168.109.4                 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>       <NA>
2     256 2024-07-10T15:02:35.203362300Z   0     0.0.0.0 192.168.109.4 microsoft.com.     0 22342 65220 16979        108


Consider XSLT, the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. R's xslt (companion to xml2), can run XSLT 1.0 scripts. Below flattens all nodes under <Event> and transforms attribute-centric names to element-centric names.
XSLT (save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:evt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Events">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="evt:Event"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="evt:Event">
        <xsl:element name="Event">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="evt:System|evt:EventData"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="evt:System">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="evt:System/*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="evt:EventData">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="evt:Data"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="evt:Data">
        <xsl:element name="{@Name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Online Demo
R (no hard-coded XML names!)
library(xml2)
library(xslt)

# LOAD XML AND XSLT
doc <- read_xml("Input.xml")
style <- read_xml("Style.xsl", package = "xslt")

# RUN TRANSFORMATION
new_xml <- xml_xslt(doc, style)

# RETRIEVE data NODES
recs <- xml2::xml_find_all(new_xml, "/*/*")

# BIND EACH CHILD TEXT AND NAME
df_list <- lapply(recs, \(r) {
  vals <- xml2::xml_children(r)
  
  df <- setNames(
    c(xml2::xml_text(vals)), c(xml2::xml_name(vals))
  ) |> rbind() |> data.frame()
})

# COMBINE ALL DFS
events_df <- do.call(rbind, normalize_frames(df_list))

Output
events_df

  EventID Version Level TimeCreated TCP InterfaceIP        Source          QNAME QTYPE   XID  Port Flags BufferSize
1     259       0     2               0     0.0.0.0 192.168.109.4                 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>       <NA>
2     256       0     4               0     0.0.0.0 192.168.109.4 microsoft.com.     0 22342 65220 16979        108

